# Garbage values are printing even after null character

Tags: c++

This code is for printing left recursion alternatives in a production.But when printing alternatives at last garbage values are being added.Why am i getting such error?

how to resolve such problem?[in the image the output is displayed.but that is the wrong output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ISZA.png)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;
class production
{
    private:
        char lhs;
        char rhs[10][10],lr[10][10];
        int noa;
    public:
        production()
        {
            noa=0;
        }
        void makeprod(char *str)
        {
            lhs=str[0];
            char r[20];
            strcpy(r,str+3);
            int j=0;
            for(int i=0;r[i]!='\0';i++)
            {
                if(r[i]!='/')
                rhs[noa][j++]=r[i];
                else
                {
                    rhs[noa++][j]='\0';
                    j=0;
                }
            }
            noa++;
        }
        void checkLR()
        {
            int ct=0,m=0;
            for(int i=0;i<noa;i++)
            if(lhs==rhs[i][0])
            {
                strcpy(lr[m],rhs[i]);
                m++;
                ct++;
            }
            if(ct>0)
            {
                for(int k=0;k<ct;k++)
                cout<<"Left recursion at "<<lr[k]<<"\n";
            }
            else
            cout<<"no\n";
        }
        void printprod()
        {
            cout<<"LHS = "<<lhs<<"\n";
            cout<<"RHS = ";
            for(int i=0;i<noa;i++)
            cout<<rhs[i]<<" ";
        }
};
int main()
{
    production p;
    char str[20];
    cout<<"enter a production\n";
    cin>>str;
    p.makeprod(str);
    p.printprod();
    p.checkLR();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please show us the input, the expected output, and the actual output.

Comment: Please provide input and expected output.

Comment: I guess that in `printprod` your `noa` value is too large and thus you access the wrong `rhs` array. Alternatively, if your input string does not end with `/`, there would be no end character inserted. You really should initialize the arrays and use overflow protections.

Comment: I have added the output what i am getting.The actual output should be without garbage values.

Comment: What is it EXACTLY what you input and what is the output that REALLY comes out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `makeprod` you're checking your input string for `/` to add the termination character to your `rhs`-array, and thus your input string has to end with the `/` sign. You have several choices :

- either initialize your arrays with 0, so the `rhs`-array is always null-terminated (**independently from your question : It's always good practice to initialize your variables**)
- add a null-termination sign (0) to `rhs` when the end of your input string is reached

**edit**: Just place a `memset(rhs, 0, sizeof(rhs)*sizeof(char));` (the same for `lr`) in your constructor and the output should be fine. This will initialize your arrays with zeroes and thus the string is null-terminated.

But you really should add some overflow checking.

Comment: for every string i am adding null character.

Comment: @AkhilReddy but only, if you find a `/` character in your string. If you reach the end of the input string, then the for-loop in `makeprod` is left without adding an additional null-character to `rhs` and thus the output shows the "garbage"

Answer (score 0):

You are propably incrementing `noa` one time too much in `makeprod()`.
That makes the for loop in `printprod()` access rhs 1 element after its end.

Comment: noa is not a problem here because,noa is counting total no. of alternatives in this program.initially noa=0,so while counting it wil have 1 value less than the total no. of alternatives.So i have incremented it.

Comment: The I can only suggest a few things: use std:.string instead of char*, use std::vector<std::string> instead of char [][], I'm sure the code will be much more clear, understandable and less error-prone. Also use initializer list in constructor, const for printprod(), etc...

Comment: Anyway, the preblem IS in printprod(), you are accessing the 'noa'th element, that is not NULL terminated. NO, you are NOT NULL terminating the last string, unless you enter '/' as last character in input.